# JavaEE servlet setAttribute what for

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, request, response, setattribute

I hope you guys will be able to help me understand the case in servlet method doGet.

for example, we have a User class with name and the last name, of course, getters and setters are set. Additional pieces of information are in comments in the code. The question is, what is the purpose of SetAttribute in this case? Should I use it? I see no difference when its on and off. Thank you in advance for your prompt response.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //here I initiate servlet to create a session yes?
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    // here im getting atribiute which is goinna be null now:
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");



    //now in case of null i want to create object which can have null atributes like name and lastname:
    if(user == null) {

        user = createUser(request);

        //here is my problem, i dont know what is it for? I already get atrributes, why would i want to set object again? to what?
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
    }

    returnInfo(response,user);




}

protected User createUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = new User();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");

    user.setName(name);
    user.setSurname(lastname);
    return user;
}

protected void returnInfo(HttpServletResponse response,User user) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
    write.println("<html>");
    write.println("<body>");
    write.println("<div>");
    if(user.getName() == null && user.getSurname() == null) {
        write.println("no person was added");
    }
    else{
        write.println("person is" + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
    }

    write.println("</div>");
    write.println("</body>");
    write.println("</html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just created a new user. It must be added to the session otherwise your user attribute will always be null.

Comment: but when i paste atribute localhost:8080/MyServlet?firstname=a&lastname=b then it will print in html a and b so how atribute will be null?